# Need dynamic checkbox list control in angular 7

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I need to implement a dropdown list controls which contains a list of checkboxes to select in my angular 7 application. Could somebody tell me in their experience if they have used similar control. Please note that the list contents would be dynamic

[image]

Html

```
 <app-checkboxes [values]="Currencies" [(ngModel)]="f.OtherCurrencyName"></app-checkboxes>
```

JSON

```
"Currencies": [
            {
                "Id": 7,
                "Name": "AUD"
            },
            {
                "Id": 10,
                "Name": "BND"
            },
            {
                "Id": 19,
                "Name": "BRL"
            },
            {
                "Id": 6,
                "Name": "CAD"
            },
            {
                "Id": 5,
                "Name": "CHF"
            },
            {
                "Id": 13,
                "Name": "CNH"
            },
            {
                "Id": 12,
                "Name": "CNY"
            },
            {
                "Id": 18,
                "Name": "DKK"
            }]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a custom component implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkboxes',
  templateUrl: './checkboxes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkboxes.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxesComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CheckboxesComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() values: string[] = [];
  selectedValues = {};

  onChange = (value: any) => { };
  onTouched = () => { };

  writeValue(initValue: any): void {
    this.selectedValues = initValue || {};
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

[Here is a running example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56237055?embed=1&file=src/app/checkboxes/checkboxes.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks how do i rendender this is dropdown like control since my list can contain even 30-40 values

Comment: This sounds like a different question, more of css than angular. But anyway, here is a solution start for that : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56237055-2

Comment: I have updated the post with the values that i am gettng from the source. I cant see that you are using string comma delimited values where as my values contain Id, Name pair. Selecting the checkboxes should select the Ids. How do I do that

Comment: You will have to change the types of  `values` to `{id: number, name: string}[] ` and the `onChange` function parameter to `number[]` and implement what you want. Here is a good article to understand `ControlValueAccessor` : https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/ . I think that I gave you everything you need to know to solve your issue, you should be able to make a code of your own.